# Mailchimp automation API returns 404 error (Resource not found)

Tags: python, curl, mailchimp

I've been assigned the task of pulling some data using the MailChimp API. So far, the script has pulled reports, campaigns, lists and member details without any issues. However, the Workflow Automation API mentioned in the docs [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/automations/emails/#read-get_automations_workflow_id_emails) isn't working. In fact, this very `CURL` example given in that doc is giving a 404 (Resource not found) error:

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/b0a1c24f1a/emails' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--include
```

I only replaced the `usX` with my own data-center number and updated my `apiKey`. In any case, here is the automation portion of my entire `automation.py` python script which my users are complaining about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import urllib2
import base64
import json
import csv
import sys
import os
import codecs
__version__ = "1.4"

##
# Configures the MailChimpExpress
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
workdir = "data/mailchimp/" 
workflow_id = "b0a1c24f1a"


##
# Writes a list to csv
#
# @param tname name of the csv file to output without extension
# @param tlist the python list to write
def write_to_csv(tname, tlist):
    myfile = open(workdir + tname + ".csv", 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for li in tlist:
        wr.writerow(li)
    myfile.close()
    return tname + ".csv"

##
# Creates a file with specified name and text content.
#
# @param tname Name of the file with extension.
# @param ttext Content to write.
def createfile(tname, ttext):
    myfile = open(workdir + tname , 'w')
    myfile.write(ttext)
    myfile.close()

##
# Pulls data from Mailchimp automation API.
def run():
    key = sys.argv[1] # CAPTURE THE API KEY

    dc = key.split("-")[-1] #this is the data-center where your request goes
    username = "anystring" #could be literally anything as per mailchimp docs!
    output = "" #var to hold raw json
    data = "" #var to hold json dict
    cnt = 0 #counter to keep track of fetched objects

    ##
    # FETCH ALL REPORTS
    #
    campaigns = []
    baseurl = "https://" + dc + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/"
    psize, i = 1000, 0

    ##
    # Lets fetch the automation data
    #
    print "Now pulling automation data (UNSTABLE AND UNTESTED FEATURE)"
    autos = []
    data ={}
    #while(True): #No longer needed as there is no limit/offset here
    turl = baseurl + "automations/" +  workflow_id + "/emails" #lists/" + lid + "/members"
    print "turl is " + turl
    if False: #DEBUG:
        tfp = open('sample_workflow_response.json')
        output = tfp.read()
        tfp.close()
    else:
        request = urllib2.Request(turl)
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, key)).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        output = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    tdata = json.loads(output)
    tcnt = len(tdata['emails'])

    print tcnt, " emails pulled."
    print ""
    print 'ID', 'position', "create_time","start_time","archive_url"

    for email in tdata["emails"]:
        print email['id'], email['position'], email["create_time"], email["start_time"], email["archive_url"]

    MailChimpExpress.createfile("lastauto.json", output)

    ###
    print "All is well.."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When I run the above code, it gives me the following output:

```
Now pulling automation data (UNSTABLE AND UNTESTED FEATURE)
turl is https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/b0a1c24f1a/emails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./automation.py", line 97, in <module>
    run()
  File "./automation.py", line 80, in run
    output = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: I'd suggestin using `requests` it's a life saver.

Comment: @taesu I know its a good suggestion and do I use `requests`. But in some situations I prefer using vanilla python and not depend on external libs. Saves the hassle of packaging and configuring.

Comment: good luck. 404 is just a 404. you should contact mail-chimp not SO.

Comment: @taesu Mailchimp guys usually respond to issues on SO. If I don't get any response soon, I'm going to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation that Mailchimp will respond to my question on SO didn't hold true this time! Instead, my client had to ask for support from Mailchimp and this is what they replied:

1. First, we have to make a call to `/automations` endpoint to retrieve the "proper" `workflow_id`.
2. Then, we have to use the above result as parameter to `/automations/{workflow_id}/emails/` endpoint and fetch the emails-sent and other data.

This technique worked, here is part of the modified code for reference:

```
    ##
    # Lets fetch the automation data now
    #
    autos = []
    data ={}
    print "Now pulling automation data (UNSTABLE AND UNTESTED FEATURE)"
    turl = baseurl + "automations"  #lists/" + lid + "/members"
    print "turl is " + turl
    if DEBUG:
        tfp = open('sample_automation_response.json')
        output = tfp.read()
        tfp.close()
    else:
        request = urllib2.Request(turl)
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, key)).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        output = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    tdata = json.loads(output)
    tcnt = len(tdata['automations'])
    workflow_id = tdata['automations'][0]["id"]
    print tcnt, " automation settings pulled. The workflow_id is " + workflow_id

    print "Now pulling automation emails using workflow_id " + workflow_id + " (UNSTABLE AND UNTESTED FEATURE)"
    autos = []
    data ={}
    #while(True): #No longer needed as there is no limit/offset here
    turl = baseurl + "automations/" +  workflow_id + "/emails/" #lists/" + lid + "/members"
    print "turl is " + turl
    if DEBUG:
        tfp = open('sample_workflow_response.json')
        output = tfp.read()
        tfp.close()
    else:
        request = urllib2.Request(turl)
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, key)).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        output = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    tdata = json.loads(output)
    tcnt = len(tdata['emails'])

    print tcnt, " emails pulled."
    print ""
    print 'ID', 'position', "create_time","start_time","archive_url"

    for email in tdata["emails"]:
        print email['id'], email['position'], email["create_time"], email["start_time"], email["archive_url"]

    MailChimpExpress.createfile("lastauto.json", output)


    ###
    print "All is well.."
```